# Help need about Andes Lineas Aereas different classes (B H K M W)

Tags: airlines, argentina

I'm booking a flight from Buenos Aires to Salta with Andes Lineas Aereas, they have different classes online, it shows B H K M W.
I found information on the website that it has something to do with luggage, change and refund of the ticket.

I wonder if it is like Latam. Are only Argentina residence eligible to get the lowest class or not? Have anyone any experience with them before?

Comment: Fare classes come with different rules for different markets and different flights.  You need to read the rules associated with the specific fare you are looking at to know exact restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, I checked their website, they didn't mention the residence, so I suppose all the classes are applied for all nationalities.

Comment: You have to read each fare's rules, you can not assume.  If you look at the specific fare rules and there is no residency requirement then yes you can buy it.  But there will not be a generic statement on their website saying X class fares are for residents only.  They don't want you to know that their citizens get better deals than you do.

Answer (score 1):

[Andes Lineas Aereas](http://www.andesonline.com/informacion/condiciones-de-tarifas/)

> **Rates Conditions**
>
> **PROMOTIONAL RATES - V - G - L - O CLASSES**
>
> Name Changes: NOT allowed
>   Refund: NOT allowed
>   Change of Date: NOT allowed
>   Combination: You are only allowed to return in the same class.
>   Leave open passage: Not allowed
>   No-Show: Full ticket loss
>
> **REDUCED RATES - CLASSES H - K - M - R - S - W - A - R**
>
> Name Changes: NOT allowed
>   Refund: NOT allowed
>   Change of Date: Allows changes of dates paying penalty and the differences to the updated rate.
>   Combination: Allows combination
>   Leave open passage: Allows to leave open for 363 days from the date of issue
>   No-Show: You must pay 25% of the rate
>
> **NORMAL RATES - CLASSES B - D**
>
> Name Changes: NOT allowed
>   Return: I allow
>   Change of Date: Allows changes of dates by paying the difference at the updated rate.
>   Combination: Allows combination
>   Leave open passage: Allows to leave open for 363 days from the date of issue
>   No-Show: You must pay 25% of the rate
>
> **Reminder:**
>
> The conditions of the tariffs always predominate the rate with lower cost.
>   Change is always the same class or Superior.